# Поле размером в несколько экранов устройства Android

Tags: android, java, gui

Здравствуйте. Задумал проект под Android, в котором мне требуется реализовать поле (Canvas, ImageView или что-то подобное им), в котором будут отрисовываться различные изображения, примитивы и так далее. При этом так же требуется реализовать несколько функций по обработке касаний пользователя в области поля (собственно, касаниями должны неким произвольным образом размещаться те самые изображения и примитивы).
Характерно то, что поле заведомо должно быть больше по размеру, чем один экран устройства (телефон, коммуникатор), скажем 640x480. Таким образом, нужно как-то организовать прокрутку по полю по обеим осям (X и Y).
Возможно ли реализовать задуманный компонент пользовательского интерфейса и если да, то какими средствами? Android позволяет размещать элементы, больше размера экрана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это безусловно возможно. Пример реализации подобного - Android one finger zoom tutorial ([часть 1](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/), [часть 2](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/26/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-2/), [часть 3](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/06/09/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-3/)).

Comment: Что ж. В ближайшее время попробую что-нибудь наваять по этому туториалу. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Самое лучшее, что мне приходит на ум сейчас - это копание исходника, например вот этой библиотеки [Тыц](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). В ней можно прокручивать графики по осям, примерно то что Вам и нужно, если я правильно понял вопрос.

Потому ответ на Ваш вопрос будет положительный: да, такое сделать можно.

Можно попробовать и другой путь: использовать например SurfaceView и реализовывать методы onMeasure, onLayout, onDraw, что думаю и делают авторы данной библиотеки. Кстать есть и другие схожие либы для рисования графиков.

Answer (score 1):

**Это не ответ, а просто рассуждение**. Мне тоже нужно было реализовать нечто подобное. Пытался поместить ScrollView в HorizontalScrollView, а внутри - лэйаут и т.д., но это отстойное решение. Судя по всему нужно действительно брать канву или image, рисовать внутри неё и считывать координаты касаний. Т.е. с одной стороны ответ на ваш вопрос - да, в андроиде такое возможно (посмотрите хотя бы на google maps или на вот это [приложение](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.piod.myHeritage&feature=related_apps)). К сожалению, точного ответа *как* это делать я дать не могу. Думаю что есть библиотеки/методы/заготовки. Поделитесь ответом, если найдёте. Удачи!

Comment: В принципе, туториал из первого поста вполне отвечает моим запросам. Импортировал проект, погонял в эмуляторе. Картинка двигается в области экрана, зумится, меня это устраивает. Однако наследник класса View (в примере именуется ImageZoomView), реализующий подобный контейнер для масштабирования картинок реализован так, что принимает только Bitmap'ы к отображению (иными словами работает с графическими пользовательскими файлами). Мне бы хотелось, чтобы он отображал различные графические примитивы (фактически объекты по схеме Shape->Drawable). Пока буду думать над тем, как изменить код.

Comment: 2antonderevyanko:
Насколько большой у вас "стаж" в разработке под Android? Сам занимаюсь буквально пару месяцев, поэтому все разработки продвигаются медленно и неуверенно. 
Понимаю, просьба может звучать глупо.
Хотел бы поинтересоваться, нет ли у вас контактов, чтобы напрямую пообщаться по отдельным аспектам написания проекта на Android? Надеюсь на помощь живого человека, самостоятельно написавшего полноценное приложение. Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: скайп derevyanko . anton (без пробелов). пишите, пообщаемся. стаж около года.